# How to export JavaFX gradle project as a standalone executable file for deployment?

Tags: java, deployment, export, javafx-11

I have completed my JavaFX application within gradle build system, and it is working fine in all way. Now I want to export as a .EXE file for standalone software distribution, I tried much more tricks but no gain. If some one can help  me out to wrap my project in a software setup, It would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Follow these steps to export your JavaFX project into executable Jar

1. Goto> Project Structure
2. Goto>>Artifacts
3. Click "+">> To add new artifact
4. It will shows a dropdownlist
5. Select>>Jar>>From module with dependencies
6. You will see a nested window as shown[image: pic2]
7. Select Main class of your project
8. Check In the Option " Copy to output directory.." >>Ok
9. Goto>> Menu-bar>>Build>>Build Artifacts
10. Select>> your Project.jar>> Build
11. This will create executable jar file in your project source folder
12. Locate your jar file in path   project\out\artifacts..
13. Now you can run this jar file simple cmd commad or with batch file

    - Cmd Command>> Java -jar project.jar
14. Using batch file>> make .bat file name it "RUN" and write these commands inside [image: Pic1]
15. Specify the Java Runtime path and "Javafx Sdk path" along with VM
     options & Project Jar
16. Run your standalone application .. Enjoy  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Creating an installer for the desktop platforms (Windows, macOS, Linux) has become easy these days. The tool of choice is jpackage which started to be shipped with JDK 14. It can either be used on the command line on the finished project or you can use a Gradle plugin (https://github.com/beryx/badass-jlink-plugin). If your project is not modularized you could follow this tutorial https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX which also uses jpackage but together with Maven and some other tools from the JDK. The Maven part could easily be rewritten to Gradle, if needed.